# Projecting a point onto the intersection of n-dimensional spaces in Python

Tags: python, numpy

(forgive my terminology - it has been a long time since I took an advanced math class)

Let's say I have *n* "planes" each "perpendicular" to a single axis in *m*-dimensional space. No two planes are perpendicular to the same axis. I believe I can safely assume that there will be some intersection between all *n* planes.

I want to project point *a* onto the intersection and get the position vector for the result.

For example:

I have a single plane whose normal vector is (0.75, 0, 0) and a point *a* at position (0.25, 0, 1). I want to get the position vector of point *a* projected onto the plane.

Another example:

I have two planes represented by normal vectors (0.5, 0, 0) and (0, 1, 0). I have a point *a* at position (0.1, 0.1, 0.1). I want to get the position vector of the point projected onto the result of the intersection between my two planes (a line)

Comment: If any of the answers below has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "planes" in *m*-dimensional space are *(m-1)*-dimensional objects. They are usually referred to as [*hyperplanes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane) — a generalization of *planes*, 2-dimensional objects in 3-dimensional space. To define a hyperplane you need not only a normal vector but also a point (think of lines in two-dimensional space: all parallel lines share the same direction, and in order to isolate one you need to specify a point).

I suspect you mean all of your hyperplanes to pass through the origin (in which case indeed there is a point in the intersection — the origin itself), and I interpret your "being perpendicular to a single axis" as saying that the normal vectors all point along some coordinate axis (in other words, they have a single nonzero component). In that case, all you have to do to find the projection of an arbitrary point (vector, really) onto the intersection is set to zero the components of the point (again, vector, really) along the normal vectors of your hyperplanes.

Let me go through your examples:

1. The (hyper)plane in 3-dimensional space with normal vector *(0.75, 0, 0)* is the *yz*-plane: the projection of an arbitrary point *(x, y, z)* is *(0, y, z)* — the hyperplane has a normal vector along the first coordinate, so set to zero the first component of the point (for the last time: vector, really). In particular, *(0.25, 0, 1)* projects to *(0, 0, 1)*.
2. The planes perpendicular to *(0.5, 0, 0)* and *(0, 1, 0)* are the *yz*- and *xz*-planes. Their intersection is the *z*-axis. The projection of the point *(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)* is *(0, 0, 0.1)*.

Answer (score 0):

The projection can be computed by solving an overdetermined system in the sense of least squares, with [lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq). The columns of the matrix of the system is formed by normal vectors, used as columns (hence, transpose on the second line below).

`coeff` are coefficients to be attached to these normal vectors; this linear combination of normal vectors is subtracted from the given point to obtain the projection

```
import numpy as np
normals = np.transpose(np.array([[0.5, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]))  # normals
point = np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1])  # point
coeff = np.linalg.lstsq(normals, point)[0]
proj = point - np.dot(normals, coeff)
print(proj)
```

Output: [0, 0, 0.1].