# How to find evenly distributed points around a point on a plane in 4D?

Tags: math, geometry, linear-algebra, probability, 4d

I'm trying to create a simulation that requires me to vary a set of probabilities, i.e., the variables must add up to 1.

When I wanted to vary the parameters of a set of 3 probabilities, I treated each parameter as an axis in 3D space and parametrized a circle on the plane x + y + z = 1 using the equations p0 + rcos(v) (dot) u1 + rsin(v) (dot) u2, where p0 is the point denoting the original probabilities, u1 and u2 are perpendicular vectors parallel to the plane, (dot) denotes a dot product, and r and v are free variables. By varying r and choosing several points along 2pi for v, I could generate a set of probabilities that were close to the original while still being valid, satisfying our constraint.

The problem I now have is when I try to do this for a set of 4 probabilities, i.e. A 4D space, I can't visualize or find a way to extend this system of equations. Is there a way to achieve something similar to what I have for the 3D case for the 4D case? Is my original way of generating probabilities for 3D stupid and if so what is the standard method of doing so?

Comment: probably worth searching [math.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First consider a different approach to the 3d case, that doesn't require any trigonometry:

You're interested in the sum of a vector's elements, call that S(**v**).

**v** = (2, 3, 5) S(**v**) = 10

And you're interested in the S = 1 plane, which has a normal vector we'll call **k**:

**k** = (1/3, 1/3, 1/3) = (1/3)(1, 1, 1)

You have a point **p<sub>0</sub>** in that plane (S(**p<sub>0</sub>**)=1), and
you want some points in the plane at a distance r from **p<sub>0</sub>**.

Start with some points chosen randomly with uniform distribution in a unit sphere around the origin x<sup>2</sup>+y<sup>2</sup>+z<sup>2</sup> < 1. (This is easy, just choose points uniformly from the cube surrounding that sphere, and reject the ones outside the sphere.)

Now project each of those points onto the S=0 plane:

**v** -> **v** - S(**v**)**k**

(Stare at that until it makes sense.) You now have points scattered in a disk of radius 1, normal to **k**. They are not uniform in the disk, they are thicker near the middle, but they are uniform in *angle.* Now scale each point to move it to the circle of radius r:

**v** -> **v** r/|**v**|

Now move the ring of points to be centered on **p<sub>0</sub>**:

**v** -> **v** + **p<sub>0</sub>**

Now here's the kicker. ***Everything you just did works in n dimensions as easily as in 3.***

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you want a uniformly distributed distribution

One way to proceed is

1. sample a 4D gaussian distribution, that is known to be evenly distributed in all directions [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1585996/928180).
2. Project the sample point in the hyperplane [2](http://faculty.salina.k-state.edu/tim/DAT/linAlg/projection/projectR3.html), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38416971/12750353).
3. Normalize the coordinates to have radius 1 (simply divide by the `sqrt(sum(x**2))`).

It is a high level approach, you can make it more efficiently for 4D, but this implementation is very easily extended to N-dimensional spaces.

Given a basis for the 4D hyperplane, you can use a 3D sampling just as you did to place the circle over the 3D plane, for a tutoria in sampling points uniformly in a 3D sphere [here](http://corysimon.github.io/articles/uniformdistn-on-sphere/), for a "official" source saying the same check [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html).